# Bootstrap Popover not displaying popover-content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am using emberjs with twitter-bootstrap, but only the css so **no** javascript taken from bootstrap.

I want to make the popover work, it pops up, but the `popover-content` is not displayed, even though it is set. Here is my code:

`popoverTemplate.hbs`:

```
<div class="popover fade right in" style="top: 12.5px; left: 242px; height:200px;width:200px; display: block;">
<div class="arrow"></div>
<h3 class="popover-title">A Title</h3>
<div class="popover-content">And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?</div>
```

My view:

```
 App.PopoverView = Ember.View.extend({
     templateName: 'popoverTemplate'
 });
```

Here is the controller issuing the toggle behavior:

```
    showPopover: null,
    init:function(){
        this.set('showPopover',false);
    },
    togglePopoverView: function(){
        this.set('showPopover',!this.get('showPopover'));
    }
```

And here is my main template, where I set the logic for the popover:

```
     {{#if showPopover}}
                {{view App.PopoverView}}
     {{/if}}
```

**UPDATE**
I figured it out, unfortunately you couldn't find the bug in my code - at least what I've put here. The problem was that in my template at the beginning I've set the context with the `#with` helper and forgot about it. So most probably I will delete this question. Thank you though for the contributions.

Comment: Is your z-index setup correctly?

Comment: make a fiddle... nobody is going to read full code and find the error

Comment: How do I include css only for bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seems to be any problem with your implementation.

Here is a working [bin](http://jsbin.com/igayaye/1/edit) with your implementation

Answer (score 1):

Register your popover when Ember insert your popover into DOM. This is what I do in my project. Not exactly, but I hope this can give you a clue to make that work.

```
App.PopoverView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'popoverTemplate',
    didInsertElement: function() {
       this.$('.popover').popover(
            {
                title: $(this).attr('data-title'),
                content: $('#popover-content').html() });
            });
    }
});
```

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<a class="popover" data-title="Title Here">Toggle Popover</a>
<div id="popover-content">
   <!-- content... -->
</div>
```

Should work without extra code, with popover toggle when you click the link.